# spring security with jsf login and index page

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security

Depending on configuration i have one of the following errors:

endless loop message from browser or "HTTP Status 404 - //pages/unsecure/index.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource" when i try to access http://localhost:8084/fresupp/

Endless loop, when login.xhtml file at /login.xhtml Config
web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/securityContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

securityContext.xml:

```
<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />  
<sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <!-- Page level Spring Security : Intercept access to resources in /pages/secure/** -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/pages/secure/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_MODERATOR')" />

    <!-- Page level Spring Security : Permit access to resources in /pages/unsecure/** -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/pages/unsecure/**" access="permitAll"/>

    <!-- Page level Spring Security : Intercept access to resources in /** -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_MODERATOR')"/>

    <!-- Define login page for Spring Security -->      
    <sec:form-login login-page="/login.xhtml"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login.xhtml" access="permitAll" />

    <!-- Page level Spring Security : Enable Primefaces -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" access="permitAll"/>


    <!-- Define logout properties for Spring Security -->
    <sec:logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="true" logout-success-url="/"></sec:logout>
</sec:http>

<!-- Set customUserDetailsService class as the authentication Manager for Spring Security-->
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <sec:password-encoder hash="plaintext"></sec:password-encoder>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>

 <!-- Inject authentication Manager to our LoginAction -->
<beans:bean id="loginAction" name="loginAction" class="com.mjavka.fresupp.actions.LoginAction" scope="request">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource message occurs when login.xhtml at "/pages/unsecure/login.xhtml" and this changes in configuration:
web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/pages/unsecure/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

securityContext.xml:

```
<sec:form-login login-page="/pages/unsecure/login.xhtml"/>
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/pages/unsecure/login.xhtml" access="permitAll" />
```

I have tried to use many different  combinations like: "/unsecure/login.xhtml" with adding `/pages/*` to `<url-pattern>` in web.xml.

When i copy and paste http://localhost:8084/fresupp//pages/unsecure/login.xhtml page opens correctly

How can i fix this configuration? 
And maybe make other page as index. From which i can go to login page.